# Replicate an UI template

Tags: html, css

I'm working on some HTML code for which I was given a UI. I tried to do most to make it look as close as possible. But I'm stuck with the header and line spacing pieces. Here is my code:

```html
<div>
  Hello, Alice! Here are your appointments for the day:
</div>
<div style="font-style:italic">
  **All times are Arizona Time**
</div>

<table style="border:1px solid #e9e9e9">
  <thead bgcolor="#8c8c8c" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9e9e9; padding:none !important">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:auto">10:00AM - 10:30AM (30 MIN)</th>
      <th style="width:auto; float:right">Abc</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div style="line-height:2em">
       Topic:</div></td>
       <td><div>Resume Review</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div style="line-height:2em">Phone:</div></td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div style="line-height:2em">Email:</div></td>
      <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div style="line-height:2em">Student notes:</div></td>
      <td>Hello,
        My resume is pretty ugly, I built it based on what I learned in TAPS in military out-processing.
        I will be standing by for the phone call, I missed my last one because I mixed up the appointment time zone.</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** I need to use the inline styling, I can't use external CSS in my system.

Here is the UI provided:

[image]

How can I match the UI and also make it responsive?

Comment: What's your actual problem? You say you have an issue with line spacing, but you're specifying `line-height: 2em` so is it just that you've not found the right values? Also, what are your constraints? Given you can't use external CSS, do you have control over the HTML structure, or do you have to work with the structure you shared? This isn't a venue to just ask for someone to hand you completed code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using table for header, you can use `div`.

Check the below code.

```html
<div>
  Hello, Alice! Here are your appointments for the day:
</div>
<div style="font-style:italic">
  **All times are Arizona Time**
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div style="width:100%; background-color:#8c8c8c; height:20px; display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:center">
    <p>10:00AM - 10:30AM (30 mins)</p>
    <p>Data</p>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="line-height:2em">
            Topic:</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Resume Review</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="line-height:2em">Phone:</div>
        </td>
        <td>1234567890</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="line-height:2em">Email:</div>
        </td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="line-height:2em">Student notes:</div>
        </td>
        <td>Hello, My resume is pretty ugly, I built it based on what I learned in TAPS in military out-processing. I will be standing by for the phone call, I missed my last one because I mixed up the appointment time zone.</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```